# Fancybox cuts off, Only in first image

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

This is very weird in Fancybox, Only first image is showing like attached, if I click/scroll next, its working properly. Can someone encounter this issue on Facebook Tab, Works fine on normal website!. Only in chrome.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My bad, Just update the chrome to  40.0.2214.93 m, It works